# Resource management in c++ game engine

Tags: c++

Currently I'm working on a way to handle resources in my game engine. It is my first iteration and I would like to expand on it in the future like asynchronous loading of resources. I am looking for some feedback and advice in order to improve it.

The API consists of the following classes.

**identifier**
Is responsible for creating unique identifiers from a string for usage in the cache(unordered_map). This is done at compile time by hashing a string to an unique int by using the fn1a algorithm

**resource_cache**
Responsibe for managing the cache, by loading/unloading resources and giving out handles to the resources.

**resource_loader**
An interface implemented by the user to load an specific resource.

**resource_handle**
Handle to an specific resource, could be containing a nullptr resource if the specific resource has not been loaded.

**Questions**
I am looking for some feedback and advice on the following topics.

- Any potential memory leaks?
- Is the API clear and concise

There is also one potential issue with dangling pointers I have yet to find an answer to. This happens when a resource is loaded and then erased, all handles given out in between will have an dangling pointer that could result in potential issues for users. I could use shared pointers but I would like to make sure a resource is unloaded once unload is called instead of keeping the resource intact till all handles are destroyed. Reference counting might sound as a nice feature but when managing large resources I would prefer to be able to unload a resource at any specific time and just reset the resource to nullptr. I might implement a specific cache for smaller resources that will implement reference counting in the future though.

**Code**
**identifier.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <utils/string_hash.h>

#include <cstring>

namespace engine
{
    namespace resources
    {
        struct identifier
        {
            using string_hash = engine_core::utils::fnv1a<uint32_t>;

            constexpr identifier(const char* identifier)
                : hash(string_hash::hash(identifier)), data(identifier)
            {
            }

            constexpr bool operator==(const identifier& rhs) const
            {
                return hash == rhs.hash;

            }
            constexpr bool operator==(const uint32_t key) const
            {
                return hash == key;
            }

            const bool operator==(const char* key) const
            {
                return strcmp(data, key) == 0;
            }

            const uint32_t hash;
            const char* data;
        };
    }
}
```

**resource_loader.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "identifier.h"

namespace engine
{
    namespace resources
    {
        template<typename T>
        class resource_cache;

        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        class resource_loader
        {
            friend class resource_cache<T>;
            virtual const T load(const identifier& key, Args... args) const = 0;
        };

    }
}
```

**resource_handle.h**

```cpp
#pragma once 

#include <assert.h>

namespace engine
{
    namespace resources
    {
        template<typename T>
        class resource_handle
        {
        public:
            resource_handle() = default;
            resource_handle(T& resource)
                : m_resource(&resource)
            {
            }

            ~resource_handle() = default;

            [[nodiscard]] T& get()
            {
                assert(m_resource != nullptr);
                return *m_resource;
            }

            [[nodiscard]] const T& get() const
            {
                assert(m_resource != nullptr);
                return *m_resource;
            }

            [[nodiscard]] explicit operator const bool() const
            {
                return static_cast<const bool>(m_resource);
            }

        private:
            T* m_resource = nullptr;
        };
    }
}
```

**resource_cache.h**

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "identifier.h"

#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace engine
{
    namespace resources
    {
        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        struct resource_loader;

        template<typename T>
        struct resource_handle;

        template<typename T>
        class resource_cache
        {
        public:
            template<typename Loader, typename... Args>
            resource_handle<T> load(const identifier& identifier, Args&&... args)
            {
                static_assert(std::is_base_of<resource_loader<T, Args...>, Loader>::value, "Loader needs to be of type resource_loader");

                static Loader loader{};

                return resource_handle<T>((m_cache.emplace(identifier.hash, std::move(loader.load(identifier, std::forward<Args>(args)...))).first)->second);
            };

            void unload(const identifier& identifier)
            {
                typename std::unordered_map<uint32_t, T>::iterator it = m_cache.find(identifier.hash);

                m_cache.erase(identifier.hash);
            }

            void clear()
            {
                m_cache.clear();
            }

            [[nodiscard]] resource_handle<T> get_handle(const identifier& identifier)
            {
                typename std::unordered_map<uint32_t, T>::iterator it = m_cache.find(identifier.hash);

                if (it == m_cache.end())
                    return resource_handle<T>();

                return resource_handle<T>(it->second);
            }

            [[nodiscard]] uint64_t size()
            {
                return m_cache.size();
            }

        private:
            std::unordered_map<uint32_t, T> m_cache;
        };

    }
}
```

**string_hash.h**
Not really looking for a review on this but is needed in order to run the rest of the code.

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

namespace engine_core
{
    namespace utils
    {
        template<typename T> struct  fnv_internal;
        template <typename T> struct fnv1;
        template <typename T> struct fnv1a;

        template <> struct fnv_internal<uint32_t>
        {
            constexpr static uint32_t default_offset_basis = 0x811C9DC5;
            constexpr static uint32_t prime = 0x01000193;
        };

        template <> struct fnv1<uint32_t> : public fnv_internal<uint32_t>
        {
            constexpr static inline uint32_t hash(char const* const aString, const uint32_t val = default_offset_basis)
            {
                return (aString[0] == '\0') ? val : hash(&aString[1], (val * prime) ^ uint32_t(aString[0]));
            }
        };

        template <> struct fnv1a<uint32_t> : public fnv_internal<uint32_t>
        {
            constexpr static inline uint32_t hash(char const* const aString, const uint32_t val = default_offset_basis)
            {
                return (aString[0] == '\0') ? val : hash(&aString[1], (val ^ uint32_t(aString[0])) * prime);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Possible implementation**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct loader : public engine::resources::resource_loader<int, int>
{
    const int load(const engine::resources::identifier& key, int value) const override
    {
        return test;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    engine::resources::resource_cache<int> cache;

    auto handle = cache.load<loader>(engine::resources::identifier("test_identifier_is_mostly_an_file_path"), 2);
    
    if (handle)
        std::cout << handle.get() << "\n";

    cache.unload(engine::resources::identifier("test_identifier_is_mostly_an_file_path"));

    // possible issue is unloaded and points to dangling pointer
    if(handle)
        std::cout << handle.get() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Enable compiler warnings and fix all warnings

My compiler produced some valid warnings about your code. In particular, if you return by value, you shouldn't make the return type `const`. It has no effect, other than to confuse you. So for example:

```
const bool operator==(const char *key) const
```

Should become:

```
bool operator==(const char *key) const
```

There are more instances of this. There is also a warning about the unused variable `it` in `engine::resources::resource_cache::unload()`.

## Why is there a `namespace engine_core`?

Why is there a separate namespace for the utility functions? Why not put them inside `namespace engine`?

## Avoid repeating names

There's `engine::resources::resource_cache`. The word "resource" is repeated twice. It is unnecessary, you could just name it `engine::resources::cache`. The same goes for `resource_handle` and `resource_loader`.

## Avoid unnecessary casts and use more `auto`

There are several places where you unnecessarily cast things, and there are places where you use long type names that can easily be deduced by the compiler. For example, in `resource_cache::get_handle()` you have:

```
typename std::unordered_map<uint32_t, T>::iterator it = m_cache.find(identifier.hash);

if (it == m_cache.end())
    return resource_handle<T>();

return resource_handle<T>(it->second);
```

This can be replaced with:

```
auto it = m_cache.find(identifier.hash);

if (it == m_cache.end())
    return {};

return it->second;
```

In the above, the `return {}` statement works because the compiler already knows the return type, and the empty initializer list `{}` matches the default constructor or the retun type. This also works for functions arguments, for example here:

```
auto handle = cache.load<loader>(engine::resources::identifier("test_identifier_is_mostly_an_file_path"), 2);
```

The compiler knows that the first argument has to be an `engine::resources::identifier`, so instead of explicitly creating such a type, you can also provide another argument that matches that of a constructor of `engine::resources::identifier`. Therefore, you can replace the above with:

```
auto handle = cache.load<loader>("test_identifier_is_mostly_an_file_path", 2);
```

## Replace `resource_handle` with a bare or a smart pointer

`class resource_haldle` is a well written wrapper around a pointer, but it doesn't do anything else besides holding a pointer and giving access to the pointer. So it can just be replaced by a bare pointer instead. What would be better is to determine what kind of ownership semantics the pointer should have that is returned by `resource_cache::load()`. If, as you mentioned in the comments in `main()`, you are worried that a handle can turn into a dangling pointer, then you should consider using [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), or possibly use `std::shared_ptr` internally and have `load()` return a [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).

For example, in `class resource_cache`, do the following:

```
template<typename T>
class resource_cache
{
public:
    template<...>
    std::weak_ptr<T> load(...) {
        ...
        return m_cache.emplace(identifier.hash, loader.load(...)).first->second;
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<T>>;
};
```

This requires `loader.load()` to return a `std::shared_ptr<T>`. Then you can use it like so:

```
engine::resources::resource_cache<int> cache;

auto handle = cache.load<loader>("test_identifier_is_mostly_an_file_path", 2);
    
if (auto resource = handle.lock())
    std::cout << *resource << "\n";
else
    std::cerr << "resource no longer in cache\n";
```

## Pass the loader as a function parameter

It is a bit weird that you have to pass the loader as a template parameter, and that the instantiation of the template `resource_cache::load<>()` will create a static variable of that type. This takes away control over the lifetime of the loader from the caller. This is why it would be better to pass the loader as a function parameter, like so:

```
template<typename Loader, typename... Args>
std::weak_ptr<T> load(Loader &loader, const identifier& identifier, Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(...);
    return m_cache.emplace(identifier.hash, loader.load(...)).first->second;
};
```

So you can call it like:

```
loader ldr;
auto handle = cache.load(ldr, "identifier", 2);
```

Or if you only need a one-shot loader:

```
auto handle = cache.load(loader{}, "identifier", 2);
```

This form also allows the loader to have a constructor that takes arguments, because it's no longer `resource_cache`'s responsibility to create an instance of the loader.

## Consider decoupling the loader from the cache

The above still looks like there is too tight a coupling between the loader and the resource cache. The only responsibility of the cache should be to store and retrieve items, nothing more. So instead of`load()` and `unload()` member functions, I would just have `insert()` and `erase()` member functions, like so:

```
std::weak_ptr<T> insert(const identifier& identifier, std::shared_ptr<T> handle)
{
    return m_cache.emplace(identifier.hash, handle).first->second;
};

void erase(const identifier& identifier)
{
    m_cache.erase(identifier.hash);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
loader ldr;
auto handle = cache.insert("identifier", ldr.load(2));
```

Of course, now `resource_cache` is basically reduced to a simple wrapper around `std::unordered_map`, the only extra thing it does is to get the hash of the identifier. And even that is unnecessary:

## Let `std::unordered_map` do the hashing for you

It's actually very silly to create a hash of an identifier and pass that as the key to a `std::unordered_map`, when the latter is already implemented as a hash table, and thus will hash the key itself! And it knows how to hash `std::string`s, so you can replace the cache with:

```
template<typename T>
class resource_cache
{
public:
    std::weak_ptr<T> insert(const char *identifier, std::shared_ptr<T> handle)
    {
        return m_cache.emplace(identifier, handle).first->second;
    };

    ...
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>> m_cache;
};
```

This will also prevent any issues from cache collisions, which your class suffers from.

## Make it an actual cache

You call it a cache, but it has none of the properties of a cache. Caches transparently load and unload resources for you, while your `resource_cache` has just manual functions to insert and remove items from a container. I would expect the following functionality:

- A single `get()` function that either returns the value from the cache, or if it doesn't exist, will load it for me.
- The cache will automatically remove (the oldest) items once a certain size is reached.